# MySQL SUM over a virtual subquery field (with another SUM) with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, subquery

I have two tables: *invoices* and *items*.

invoices

```
id | timest
```

items

```
id | invoice_id | price | qty
```

It is apparent an invoice may have several items - *items.invoice_id = invoices.id*.

I have the following query that selects all invoices with the total sum of theirs items:

```
SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(inv.time), "%Y-%m" ) AS _period, 
(SELECT SUM(it.price*it.quantity) FROM items AS it WHERE it.invoice_id=inv.id) as total 
FROM `invoices` `inv`
```

This generates something like:

```
id| _period | total
-------------------
1 | 2014-06 | 100
4 | 2014-06 | 200
5 | 2014-07 | 660
6 | 2014-07 | 300
7 | 2014-07 | 30
9 | 2015-02 | 225
```

Now I want to group it by the period to have output as:

```
_period | qty | total_price
---------------------------
2014-06 |  2  | 300
2014-07 |  3  | 990
2015-02 |  1  | 224
```

I can easily do it for the quantity field as

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(inv.time), "%Y-%m" ) AS _period,
COUNT(inv.id) as qty
FROM `invoices` `inv`
GROUP BY _period
```

But I can't figure out how the similar thing could be done for the total_price field, which results from a subquery virtual field? Does anyone have any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this using a `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(i.time, '%Y-%m') AS _period, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT i.id) as num_invoices
       SUM(i.price * it.quantity) as total
FROM invoices i LEFT JOIN
     items it
     ON it.invoice_id = i.id
GROUP BY _period
ORDER BY _period;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT InnerTable._period, Count(InnerTable.id) as id, Sum(InnerTable.total) as total FROM
    (SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(inv.time), "%Y-%m" ) AS _period, 
(SELECT SUM(it.price*it.quantity) FROM items AS it WHERE it.invoice_id=inv.id) as total 
FROM `invoices` `inv`) as InnerTable FROM GROUP BY InnerTable._period.
```

Making sub table from the query and then put group by on it.